# How can we create Deep Links for React Native applications without using any other libraries?

Tags: android, deep-linking, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm a newbie in android programming and creating application on React Native framework. I am trying to create Deep Links for my application which I have already implemented with [Branch](http://branch.io). But since this has been implemented using a library, it might create some unwanted problems in future, because of the fact that the React Native community are actively working on to improve this platform.

I want some Native way of creating deep links with React Native applications. I would love to hear your opinions here.
Thank you.

Comment: https://www.lullabot.com/articles/navigation-and-deep-linking-with-react-native

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html

Comment: @SouravGanguly both the links lacks to actually implement deeplink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex from Branch here:

We are actively involved in the React Native community, and aren't going anywhere. Using the Branch library in your app definitely won't cause issues later.

Deep linking isn't actually something React Native can solve in isolation, because the standards and underlying requirements all come from the iOS and Android platforms on which React Native is built. If you're interested in reading more about the issues behind mobile deep linking, check out [this article](https://hackernoon.com/the-death-of-deep-linking-6cc65eb33e28) for details on why it's such a complex problem.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Alex. This is something I was waiting for.